# Particular content in richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to display some bold and some simple content in the form so I am using richtextbox.And I have made one file with extension of .rtf.Now I load that file in the richtextbox with use of the Loadfile() function.This works. But I want to display particular content of the file in the richtextbox,like may be first five lines or it may be line no. of six to ten.Then is there any solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, just not very cleanly.  This code uses another RTB to load the file and the clipboard to get the formatted RTF.  Beware that it destroys the clipboard content.

```
  using (var helper = new RichTextBox()) {
    helper.LoadFile(@"c:\temp\test.rtf");
    // Copy line #6
    int startRange = helper.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(5);
    int endRange = helper.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(6);
    helper.SelectionStart = startRange;
    helper.SelectionLength = endRange - startRange;
    helper.Copy();
  }
  richTextBox1.SelectAll();
  richTextBox1.Paste();
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't preserve any formatting, but shows how you could manipulate the Lines array.  It looks like the RichTextBox selfishly keeps all RTF codes to itself and only exposes text through Lines:

```
        var fromStart = new string[richTextBox1.Lines.Length - start];
        Array.Copy(richTextBox1.Lines, start, fromStart, 0, fromStart.Length);
        var lineSet = fromStart.Take(count).ToArray();
        richTextBox1.Lines = lineSet;
```

start and count are passed into this function that selects a set of lines.

Comment: Nice try, but I think it's not going to be an accepted answer. His requirements include keeping the formatting (I found this out from his comments on another question).

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `ReadAllLines`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
int startLine = lines.IndexOf(startMarker);
int endLine = lines.IndexOf(endMarker);
if (startLine == -1 || endLine == -1)
{
    // throw some sort of exception - the markers aren't present
}
string[] section = new string[endLine - startLine - 1];
Array.Copy(lines, startLine + 1, section, 0, section.Length);
richTextBox.Rtf = string.Join("\r\n", section);
```

Solution using `ReadAllText`:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
int startIndex = text.IndexOf(startMarker);
int endIndex = text.IndexOf(endMarker, startIndex + startMarker.Length);
if (startIndex == -1 || endIndex == -1)
{
    // throw some sort of exception - the markers aren't present
}
richTextBox.Rtf = text.Substring(startIndex + startMarker.Length,
                                 endIndex - startIndex - startMarker.Length);
```

Both of these assume that you really have got a complete RTF document in that section of the file though - you may well find you need additional header text, for example. Also, both assume the file is in UTF-8. I don't know enough about the RTF format to know if that's correct.

Comment: @sir Jon Skeet It gives error like-- File format is not valid --on the last line.

Comment: This code could only work if the file contains plain text, not RTF.  In which case it should assign the Text property, not the Rtf property.

Comment: @nobugz: If it contains RTF delimited by markers, why would it fail? @Harikrishna: That suggests it's not a complete valid RTF document between the markers, as explained in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Sir Jon Skeet Thank You sir for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the Lines property? It allows set / get string array as the RichTextbox content.

Comment: Try ProfK reply. He is using Lines property.

Comment: Ja, but it doesn't preserve formatting properly, as I said in my edit.