# Accessing the content of the file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
//Introduction
Hey, Welcome.....
This is the tutorial 
//EndIntro

//Help1
Select a Stock
To use this software you first need to select the stock. To do that, simply enter the stock symbol in the stock text-box (such as "MSFT"). 
To continue enter "MSFT" in the stock symbol box.
//EndHelp1

//Help2

Download Stock Data
Next step is to to download the stock data from the online servers. To start the process simply press the "Update" button or hit the <ENTER> key.
After stock data is downloaded the "Refresh" button will appear instead. Press it when you want to refresh the data with the latest quote.
To continue make sure you are online and press the "Update" button
//EndHelp2
```

First time I want to display the content between //Introduction and //EndIntro then second time the content between //Help1 and //EndHelp1 and so on.

Comment: You have posted almost this exact same question before twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990703/displaying-particular-content-of-the-file-in-the-richtextbox-in-winforms and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990937/particular-content-in-richtextbox. You should improve your existing questions instead of reposting the same question over and over. You should include a full description of what you are trying to do in the question.

Comment: The way you are trying to approach this is giving yourself extra challenges that are not even necessary. Have you considered using HTML or XML instead of using RTF? There is an abundance of tools for parsing these document formats, plus good built-in support in .NET. Plus there are many more people here with an in-depth knowledge of HTML/XML parsing than there are with RTF parsing. If you can change your requirements to reading a HTML document you can have this problem solved within a few hours. If you insist on sticking to RTF then you'll probably have to solve this mostly on your own.

Comment: @mark-byers  But,in the richtextbox can I load the html or xml file and second issue is that I have requirment of some bold and some simple font in the same file so I want to use rtf file.And is there any other solution of writing some simple and some bold font within the same file?

Comment: @Harikrishna: No, if you write the file in HTML you would also have to use a component that can display HTML instead.

Comment: You could also use something like a subset of the markdown language that this site uses. Eg. to make something bold, surround it by \*\*double stars\*\* which would give this: **double stars**. That would be very simple for humans to read and write and simple to parse and to convert and display as HTML, RTF or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very open-ended question - what sort of file? To read binary data from it you'd usually use:

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    // Read from the stream here
}
```

or

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

To read text you could use any of:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
{
    // Read from the reader
}
```

or

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

or

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
```

If you could give more details about the kind of file you want to read, we could help you with more specific advice.

EDIT: To display content from an RTF file, I suggest you load it as text (but be careful of the encoding - I don't know what encoding RTF files use) and then display it in a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) control by setting the [`Rtf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) property. Make the control read-only to avoid the user editing the control (although if the user *does* edit the control, that wouldn't alter the file anyway).

If you only want to display *part* of the file, I suggest you load the file, find the relevant bit of text, and use it appropriately with the `Rtf` property. If you load the whole file as a single string you can use `IndexOf` and `Substring` to find the relevant start/end markers and take the substring between them; if you read the file as multiple lines you can look for the individual lines as start/end markers and then concatenate the content between them.

(I also suggest that next time you ask a question, you include this sort of detail to start with rather than us having to tease it out of you.)

EDIT: As Mark pointed out in a comment, RTF files should have a header section. What you've shown isn't really an RTF file in the first place - it's just plain text. If you *really* want RTF, you could have a header section and *then* the individual sections. A better alternative would probably be to have separate files for each section - it would be cleaner that way.

Comment: @Harikrishna - RTF is largely a text-based format, so `ReadAllText` will get the raw RTF, but that does **not** make it any easier to understand the contents... perhaps what you want is an RTF parser...

Comment: @Mr Jon Skeet Can you say that how to display part of the file

Comment: @Harikrishna: I've already outlined how you'd do it: load the whole file, find the start and end markers, take the text between them, and then set the `Rtf` property with that substring.

Comment: @Mr Jon Skeet You mean that load the whole file into the richtextbox by richtextbox.Loadfile("path") function.Then it will display whole the content of the file in the richtextbox.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I don't think it's quite that simple. You need a header too. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140298%28office.10%29.aspx for the RTF specs.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Can you explain in detail please how to load the whole file, find the start and end markers, take the text between them, and then set the Rtf property with that substring.

Comment: @Mark: Interesting point. It doesn't look like it's really an RTF file to start with, to be honest - it looks like plain text to me... @Harikrishna: No, I'm afraid I'm too busy to give more explanation than I've already given. I've already explained which method calls will load the whole file, and pointed to IndexOf and Substring. You're going to have to do some work yourself. Try what I've suggested, and if you get stuck show us what you've already done. If we just give you the complete code you'll never really learn anything.

Comment: Yes, sir it is..But I have tried to do that but I did not get the solution.

Comment: If you've tried, you should be able to show *what* you've tried. That way we can help you to *learn*.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question correctly. But you can read and write content using System.IO.StreamReader and StreamWriter classes

```
string content = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\sample.txt"))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Sample1.txt"))
{
    sw.Write(content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs more clarification. Look at [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) for many ways to read data.

The easiest way of reading a text file is probably this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
```

Note that this automatically handles closing the file so no using statement is need.
If the file is large or you don't need all lines you might prefer to reading the text file in a streaming manner:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(path))
{
     while (true)
     {
         string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
         if (line == null)
         {
             break;
         }
         // Do something with line...
     }
}
```

If the file contains XML data you might want to open it using an XML parser:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var nodes = doc.Descendants();
```

There are many, many other ways to read data from a file. Could you be more specific about what the file contains and what information you need to read?

Update: To read an RTF file and display it:

```
richTextBox.Rtf = File.ReadAllText("input.rtf");
```

Comment: richTextBox.Rtf = File.ReadAllText("input.rtf");

Comment: Is //start and //end text found inside the rtf text? Do they appear on lines of their own? What if they appear more than once? What else do you need to do apart from this?

Comment: Does "richTextBox.Rtf = File.ReadAllText("input.rtf");" correctly display the entire text, without the filtering? If not, what error do you get?

Comment: then lines between //control1 and //endControl1

Comment: No it does not give the error but I dont want to display entire text,but I want to display particular lines between some define words.